# How to declare static const struct elements inside a class

Tags: c++, struct, constants

Inside a class, I want to declare a structure with some variables. The variables are all const.

The relevant code is the following:

```
class DataStructure
{
    struct globals
    {
        //some other data types
        static const int MAX_MOTORS = 8;
    }static const GLOBALS;

public:
    std::string s[GLOBALS.MAX_MOTORS];
}
```

The role of that structure is to keep some class variables organized and make them available all around the class.

But I still not get a constant value as I'am facing with the following error:

```
error: array bound is not an integer constant before ']' token std::string s[GLOBALS.MAX_MOTORS];
```

No C++11 available for now.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you not using *enumerations* for simple integer constants? Or is the structure supposed to hold other fields as well?

Comment: As for your problem, try using `constexpr` instead of plain `const`? And even if you don't want to use enumerators but still only have simple integer constants in the structure, what is the need for the `GLOBALS` variable? Can't you just use `globals::MAX_MOTORS` like most other people that use static member variables?

Comment: FYI gcc will compile it since [4.6.4](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wkcix75MYYiTMhbC)

Comment: Can't use enum as there are not only int data types.

Comment: @caffeine If you're pre-C++11 you're right only `int`'s could be initialized inline. And by the same token, `struct globals` would not be initialized. Thus you couldn't use `GLOBALS` as though it was initialized. Thus your code will work on C++11 as everyone is so quick to mention, but pre-C++11 you'll need to use `globals::MAX_MOTORS` instead of `GLOBALS.MAX_MOTORS`

Comment: Thank you @Someprogrammerdude. `static constexpr int MAX_MOTORS = 8;` solved my problem!  Now I just have to understand differences between `constexpr` and `const`.

Comment: `constexpr` is C++11 only. So you kinda need to get straight whether you're using C++11 or not.

Comment: I have tried the code with Qt but they enable C++11 by default and I didn't know that. Returning to old compiler, I got: `note: C++11 'constexpr' only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11`. And yes, `globals::MAX_MOTORS` seems to be the best option!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461868/how-to-declare-static-const-struct-elements-inside-a-class#comment75921365_44461868):

> Can't use enum as there are not only int data types

You are referencing the fact that pre-[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) `static const` intialization could only happen:

> With integral or enumeration types, and that the initializer expression must be an expression that can be evaluated at compile-time <sup>[[1](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-const-with-initializers)]</sup>

Now, as such the `GLOBALS` member cannot be initialized until the implementation file. Thus using `GLOBALS` as though it is initialized won't work. Instead you can reference the `static const` member of the `globals` type without having an initialized object. So you're line should become:

```
std::string s[globals::MAX_MOTORS];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should definitely work! 
I am using GCC 4.9.2 and tried it.

But as Jonathan Mee already pointed out in a comment:
If you are using any version below C++11, only static const integers will be inline initialized. Since globals is a struct this is a problem. I suggest changing your code to the following:

```
class DataStructure
{
    private:
      static const int MAX_MOTORS = 8;

    public:
      std::string s[MAX_MOTORS];
}
```

You could also put MAX_MOTORS into the header file!